keycloak service account authentication
Prerequisites:

keycloak is running in docker using image keycloak/keycloak:latest
added a new Client (service account), which has a Client ID and a Client Secret as in picture below
default realm is master


In postman I've authenticated using client_credentials grant type and got the JWT access token in response (from endpoint http://localhost:7080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token).
Now I would like to authenticate in my dotnet 8 WebApi microservice using the JWT token that I got from postman. The configuration is:
    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "http://host.docker.internal:7080/realms/master";
            options.Audience = "account";
            options.MetadataAddress = "http://host.docker.internal:7080/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:7080/realms/master",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "account",
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
            };

            options.UseSecurityTokenValidators = false;
        });

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

the endpoint is secured
app.MapGet("/secret", (ClaimsPrincipal user) => $"Hello {user.Identity?.Name}. My secret").RequireAuthorization();

When accessing the secure endpoint I get the error
Failed to validate the token.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(JsonWebToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, BaseConfiguration configuration)

Could someone please explain to me what is wrong in this code? If I understand corrently - I do not necessary need to provide the "signing key" because I have a service account authentication type. Meaning that the keycloak itself should be able to validate the token signature using the private secret key that it possess.
So the error makes no sense to me..
In any case, I also tried setting the secret key (same as client secret?) manually
ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
IssuerSigningKey = new JsonWebKey("vKgbRKwmv9YH42OSMFnofQxCh8d92jX2"), // this OR next
IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("vKgbRKwmv9YH42OSMFnofQxCh8d92jX2")), // this OR next

but this does not resolve the issue and produces new error messages about invalid key format.. Any ideas how to fix or explanations for failure are much appreciated!
the ONLY working solution so far is completely disabling the signing key verification using the
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                SignatureValidator = delegate (string token, TokenValidationParameters parameters)
                {
                    return new Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JsonWebToken(token);
                },

but then I would assume that this would be the same as letting anybody use any randomly signed JWT token which is not what I want :)

Alright, I think I've been able to figure it out.
An important piece of information missing from my post is that the default encryption for the client is RS256, meaning - an asymmetric algorithm.
See the JWT header
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "LSx-RczcXcqiEwgBZuOCcSc91QfNg7u2fnPGDUhzxac"
}

The keycloak is using the private key to sign the JWT, but the client apps such as dotnet webapi are using the public key to validate it. This was the beginning of the realization on now to fix the problem.
    string publicKey = "your public key goes here";

    var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey), out _);

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:7080/realms/master",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "account",
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa),
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidAlgorithms = new[]
                {
                    "RS256"
                }
            };
        });

In the solution we are defining the signing key as Rsa key specifically and setting the public key value.
I have also gotten rid of MetadataAddress and the Authority address.. This would be very helpful to know why exactly are these fields and why the are not required for my use-case.. If anybody has an answer please post it in the comment section below.
I initially was under the impression that the dotnet application will make a call to the auth provider, get it's public key automatically, validate the incoming request and be done with it.
And now it looks like this process is not actually automated by the framework and relies on the developer on providing the public key in config.
Further improvements: there are probably ways to get the "public key" from the keycloack REST endpoint and cache it, instead of hardcoding it in the client app config.

Istruggled for hours to understand why dotnet wasn't able to pick up the keys from the ".well-known/openid-configuration". I found out my problem was that I was running both in docker containers, so the URL I was using http://localhost:8080 should've always been http://host.docker.internal:8080 instead. I changed that and using a very basic TokenValidationParameters with issuer and audience it started outright working.
